# Relationship between nullspace and row/column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$, whose null space is a line through the origin in $3$-space. Can the row or column space of $A$ also be a line through the origin ?

Comment: **Hint**: The rank is the dimension of the rowspace is the dimension of the columnspace.

Comment: Do you know rank nullity theorem?

Comment: I know that $rank (A) + \text{nullity} (A) = n$, however I do not see how this will help me. I feel so stupid now =(

Comment: What is the dimension of a line through the origin?

Comment: I think I might have gotten this now. The dimension is three right?

Comment: $n$ is $3$ (the matrix is $3\times 3$); the dimension of a *line through the origin* is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the null-space of $A$ is a line, which is a 1-dimensional subspace, the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells us, that the rank of the matrix, which is the dimension of its row/column-space, is 2 and therefore the column-space cannot be a line, but a plane, a 2-dimensional subspace.